# Reading and Parsing Excel in .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have googled, and rummaged through stackoverflow with no luck on the matter.

I have found countless ways to import an entire excel file into a datagridview, but this is not what I want.

Basically, I have an excel file with multiple users (in one column) and a unique ID in another column. I want to only parse specific users and the corresponding unique ID from that row.

How Can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what are you using to parse the Excel file, Excel Com NPOI, Other ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to read the contents of an Excel file.  One possibility is to use Excel's object model through the Excel Interop API.  Using this approach, you'll interact with Excel using objects:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class ExcelReader
    Public Sub Read(filename As String)
        Dim excel As New Excel.Application
        Dim book As Excel.Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = book.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim first_cell_text As String = sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value().ToString
        Dim a_number As Integer = sheet.Cells(1, 2).value
    End Sub
End Class
```

You need to add a reference to the Excel interop DLL, which on my machine is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll.  I am pretty sure you need to have Excel installed on any machine that runs the app, too.

Documentation for the Excel object model is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel(v=office.15).aspx).

Other options include [reading an Excel file as if it were a database using ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567155/Work-with-MS-Excel-and-ADO-NET), and using [third party libraries](https://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ExcelNET/) that can read Excel.